# Sync remote bitbucket repository with downloaded local repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a large repository on Bit Bucket (2GB+). When I try to clone the repository the connection hanged up unexpectedly and then I had to start from scratch again.

I have tried cloning the repository many times with no success. As a solution I have downloaded the remote repo in `.zip` format.

After extracting I have the repository on my local machine but am unable to sync it with remote repository (BitBucket). The .zip repository does not have the hidden .git folder hence i am not able to push my changes to remote.

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to push my local changes to the remote repository / sync the local folder with remote so that it will have all the git histories.

Comment: You will have to get the `git clone` to succeed.

Comment: Try using a shallow clone that you gradually deepen, and then when it's mostly done, use `git fetch --unshallow` to finish the deepening. Note: Bitbucket generally place size limits on repositories, so once you *do* have a clone, you might still not be able to upload new commits to BItbucket.